# Are all the questions gone?

Tags: support

Is it just me, or are others seeing 0 Questions on the main site this morning?

Other StackExchange sites seem normal. Are there problems only with Workplace?

Comment: And they're back! Very odd.

Comment: This is a bug that happens from time to time and has happened on other sites as well. I'm having some trouble digging up any real information about it right now though.

Comment: [Related](http://fc03.deviantart.net/images2/i/2003/52/1/2/But_why_is_the_rum_gone_.jpg)